# Cómo transporto objetos por funciones en clases?

Tags: php, objeto, class

Esto es el código que tengo:

```
class One
{
    public string $data = '';

    public function getData(string $data) : void
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function printData() : void
    {
        echo $this->data . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$p = new One;
$p->getData("Esto es la información");
$p->printData(); // Imprime "Esto es la información"
```

Pues quiero que haga lo mismo, pero con la variable junta, o sea, esto:

```
$p = new One;
$p->getData("Esto es la información")->printData();
```

No entiendo muy bien esto sobre objetos, ¿podrían ayudar?

Comment: Obviamente no es para imprimir simplemente un string, quiero hacer algo más elaborado, pero, primero debo comprender esto de una manera optima.

Comment: No logro comprender que error quieres solucionar... Haces una llamada a cada funcion, entonces, ¿Que variable quieres enlazar?

Comment: Quiero transportar los datos de "getData()" a "printData()", esto en la misma variable, y no es un error, más bien es otra manera de trabajar los datos

Comment: Quieres ´$p->printData($p); // Imprime "Esto es la información"´ ?? No comprendo. Como lo unico existente dentro de One es $data, si muestras $p te saldrá la data cargada... Por eso te digo, no hay variables ahi, solo hay 2 funciones llamadas. Una obtiene la data, la otra la imprime.

Comment: Debes devolver en cada función el mismo objeto, si entiendo bien lo que tratas de hacer.

Comment: Ignoren mi clase, es solo para que se den una idea de lo que quiero hacer, lo que realmente importa es el cómo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como digo en mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/574800/c%c3%b3mo-transporto-objetos-por-funciones-en-clases#comment1016089_574800), lo que podrías hacer es devolver (en los métodos que lo necesites) el objeto que ha sido instanciado, para que puedas encadenar las llamadas, tal como muestras en tu pregunta.

Por ejemplo:

```php
<?php
class One
{
    public string $data = '';

    public function getData(string $data) : One  // <- devuelvo un objeto tipo One
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        return $this;  // <- devuelvo el objeto
    }

    public function printData() : void
    {
        echo $this->data . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$p = new One();
$p->getData("Esto es la información p");
$p->printData(); // Imprime "Esto es la información p"

$p2 = new One();
$p2->getData("Esto es la información p2")->printData(); // establece "Esto es la información p2" y luego imprime
```

Como observas, el método `getData` devuelve un objeto de tipo `One`. Esto quiere decir que puedes encadenar la llamada a `printData()` inmediatamente a la llamada de `getData()`.

**Nota:** Esto funcionará en PHP 7.4 o posterior.

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.

Comment: pro, funciona :)

Comment: @Ivan si la respuesta es útil, [puedes votar a favor y marcarla como válida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), eso nos da puntuación a ambos. Saludos